# protractor gulp run a single spec file

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gulp, jasmine, protractor

Here is my protractor conf file

exports.config = {
    framework: 'jasmine',

```
seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

specs: ['../../e2e/smoke-test/*.spec.js'],

ignoreSynchronization: 'true',

jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 2500000,
    allScriptsTimeout: 25000000
}

};
```

Here is my gulp conf file

```
'use strict';

var path = require('path');
var gulp = require('gulp');

// Protractor configurations to open browser
var protractor = require("gulp-protractor").protractor;
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn; 


var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

var $ = require('gulp-load-plugins')();

// Downloads the selenium webdriver
gulp.task('webdriver-update', $.protractor.webdriver_update);

gulp.task('webdriver-standalone', $.protractor.webdriver_standalone);

// Protractor with selenium configuration to open browser

//run webdriver method
function runWebdriver(callback) {
  spawn('webdriver-manager', ['start'], {
    stdio: 'inherit'
}).once('close', callback);
}

//run protractor configurations method
function runProtractorSeleniumConfig() {
gulp.src('./**/*-page.spec.js')
    .pipe(protractor({
        configFile: './e2e/conf/smoke-test-conf.js'
    }))
    .on('error', function (e) {
        throw e;
    });
}

//execute protractor.config after webdriver is executed

function runWebdriverProtractor(){
// runWebdriver(runWebdriver);
runWebdriver(runProtractorSeleniumConfig);
}

//put them into 
gulp.task('e2e:smoke-test', runWebdriverProtractor);
// run on dist
//gulp.task('e2e:dist', ['serve:e2e-dist', 'webdriver-update'],  runProtractor);
```

right now I defined one task for gulp which is

```
gulp e2e:smoke-test
```

I runs all specs under smoke-test what can I do if I want to run a single smoke spec file or if I want to run a single spec/test

Comment: you can mark the test as `fit` or `fdescribe` to run them specifically

Comment: You can run a single spec file with --specs mydir/mytestfile.js

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved this by passing an individual file through gulp configuration.

```
function runProtractorSeleniumConfig(path) {
  gulp.src(getFile(path))
    .pipe(protractor({
        configFile: 'ProtractorConfigFile'
    }))
    .on('error', function (e) {
        throw e;
    });
 }
function getFile(ext){
  if(ext == '--regression'){
    return 'RegressionTestCaseFilePath'
  }
  else{
    return 'TestCaseFilePath'
  }
}
```

//execute protractor.config after webdriver is executed

```
function runWebdriverProtractor(str){
  // runWebdriver(runWebdriver);
  runWebdriver(runProtractorSeleniumConfig(str));
}
```

//run smoke test commands configurations

```
gulp.task('e2e:smoke-test', function(){
  runWebdriverProtractor(process.argv[3])
});
```

now I can run regression/smokde file by simply using this

```
gulp e2e:smoke-test  --smoke
```

cheers!!

Answer (score -1):

With jasmine2 you can filter tests using a regular expression. Maybe you can add something like @smoke, @regressions to your tests and then only run those ones by passing the grep flag:

```
describe('Test Spec @smoke', function () {
    ...
    })
```

and in protractor.conf.js:

```
exports.config = {
      jasmineNodeOpts: {
         grep: '@smoke',
  }
};
```